# Creating directory structure

Tags: linux, directory, directory-structure

I have been given an homework assignment for Linux that reads:

> Create a tree of files as shown in the image in the user home directory(用户主目录), listing all the commands that complete the process.

[image]

My issue is that I don't know what command(s) I should be using to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `mkdir -p /path/to/directory` creates all the intermediate directories, so you only need to issue a command for the "leaf" directories.

Answer (score 1):

A tree of files should be a directory structure.

Then there is one detail: to use parens to not get lost.

```
mkdir private public temp
(cd private; mkdir lab ...)
(cd public; mkdir music book ...)

(cd public/book; mkdir java c++ Pascal)
```

This imitates the way you would do it interactively, with `cd ..` maybe to return to the higher level.

Answer (score 1):

A single directory can be created using the `mkdir` command on the command line.  For example:

```
mkdir private
```

This would create the directory `private` in the current directory.

Your exercise asks for a series of commands that creates the show directory structure, so this would be a series of `mkdir` commands.

There are basically two ways you could solve this assignment:

1. Move to your home directory (with `cd`), and then create each directory that is needed there.  Then `cd` into one of them and create each directory that is needed there etc., or
2. Move to you home directory, then use `mkdir -p` with the paths of the bottom-most directories only.  The `-p` option to the `mkdir` command would create the directory at the end of the specified path, but would also create any intermediate directories if they are missing.  For example:

   ```
   mkdir -p private/homework private/lab
   ```

   would create both the `private` directory and the `homework` and `lab` subdirectories beneath it.

See also the output of `man mkdir` on you system.